# Python: add a class to another classes bases

Tags: python, inheritance

im trying to add a class to another classes bases:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class AMixin(object):
    def mixinExample(self):
        return ("in AMixin.mixinExample" + self.name)

def MixIn(TargetClass, MixInClass):
    if MixInClass not in TargetClass.__bases__:
        TargetClass.__bases__ += (MixInClass,)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_instance = A("Q7")
    MixIn(A,AMixin)
    print(a_instance.mixinExample())
```

and i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases object, AMixin
```

I got this error because both of the classes (A and AMixin) inherent from 'object'?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set `A`'s bases to `(object, AMixin)`. This ordering means that `object` methods should override `AMixin` methods.

However, `AMixin` inherits from `object`, and that means that `AMixin` methods should override `object` methods.

It is not possible for both of those requirements to be satisfied, hence the error.